# SET method is not working the first time unless app is refreshed - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to `setPackages` in `useEffect` everything is working fine except `setPackages` method. It do not work first time but when I refresh app by saving CTRL+S from VS Code it works and `setPackages` works.

Following is the code.

```
const [packages, setPackages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   const getPackages = async () => {
      Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(true);
      Purchases.setup("MY_KEY_HERE");
      try {
        const offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
        if (offerings.current !== null) {    
           console.log(offerings.current.availablePackages); //This displays the data (works)
           setPackages(offerings.current.availablePackages); //This do not set the data in packages unless app refreshed
        }else{
            console.log("No offerings found");
        }
      } catch (e) {
         console.log("Error => " + e);
      }
   }
   getPackages();
},[])
```

I need to refresh app every time to make this line work. What could be issue here?

Comment: you don't call getPackages in the useEffect, you just declare the function?

Comment: I call that, let me update the code. Forgot to mention.

Comment: Since the console.log() of the results works, it means you actually *do* receive your expected data. I'm wondering; how are you currently displaying the `packages` variable?

Comment: can you try this way `setPackages([...offerings.current.availablePackages]);` ?

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring the function, but not calling it. And you should include an empty deps array in useEffect if you want this to be call once on start and not over and over again.

```js
const [packages, setPackages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   const getPackages = async () => {
      Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(true);
      Purchases.setup("MY_KEY_HERE");
      try {
        const offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
        if (offerings.current !== null) {    
           console.log(offerings.current.availablePackages); //This displays the data (works)
           setPackages(offerings.current.availablePackages); //This do not set the data in packages unless app refreshed
        }else{
            console.log("No offerings found");
        }
      } catch (e) {
         console.log("Error => " + e);
      }
   };
   getPackages();
},[])
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add in my code, but I am calling that `getPackages` function that's why everything else inside that function works.

Comment: Do you still have the issue with included empty dependency array?

Comment: Yes Sir. Still Same issue, even with empty array.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest [this hook](https://gist.github.com/mariusbrataas/ffca05c210ec540b4fb9f4324c4f2e68) to handle your `packages`-state?

Use it like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  // Load packages (will be undefined while loading or updating)
  const packages = usePromiseMemo(() => {
    Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(true);
    Purchases.setup('MY_KEY_HERE');
    return Purchases.getOfferings().then(offerings => {
      if (offerings.current) {
        console.log(offerings.current.availablePackages); //This displays the data (works)
        return offerings.current.availablePackages;
      } else {
        console.log('No offerings found');
      }
      return undefined;
    });
  }, []); // Alternatively: Replace [] with [Purchases]

  // Render
  return <div>More stuff here</div>;
}
```

I don't know where `Purchases` comes from, but add it to the dependency array if it is subject to change.

Also, if 'MY_KEY_HERE' is stored in some variable, add that to the dependency array too.